# C loops infinitely at scanf()

Tags: c

I'm new to C and I've checked for some solutions, though I can only find stuff for chars (and tried their solutions with chars), it didn't work aswell, I want to know why I'm infinitely looping (Can't input anything aswell). What I expect is a new input when I enter for example a letter.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma warning(disable:4996)

int main(void)
{
  float num1;
  while (!(scanf("%f", &num1)))
   {
     scanf("%f", &num1);
   }
}
```

Comment: This question is coming up like every 10'th C question. You have a weird variation though. When `scanf` is failing, the characters remain in the input stream, so there is no point to attempt the same thing again.

Comment: How could I, if the number is not valid, ask for another input and check if that one is valid?

Comment: The general advice would be to stop using `scanf`. Use `fgets` to get the full string until end of line or end of file, and then parse it using your favorite method (even `sscanf` will do)..

Comment: I'm not familiar with other commands due to just starting with C. IS there no simpler way to get the same result? If not I'll hook myself up with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- When you enter the first input as a number, the loop exits as expected
- When you enter a character, scanf will returns 0 since it has not read a correct input(since scanf returns the number of input items assigned). Thus it enters the for loop, but when you enter the number correctly you expect the scanf to return 1 and exit the loop.
  But the previous input is still remains in the buffer.
  One possible solution is

```
#include <stdio.h>
float get_float_input() {
  // Not portable
  float num1;
  while (!(scanf("%f", &num1))) {
    fseek(stdin, 0,
          SEEK_END); // to move the file pointer to the end of the buffer
  }
  return num1;
}
float get_float_input_func() {
  // Portable way
  float num1;
  int ch;
  char buff[1024];
  while (1) {
    if (fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), stdin) == NULL) {
      while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF)
        ; // Clearing the input buffer
      continue;
    }
    if (sscanf(buff, "%f", &num1) != 1) {
      continue;
    }
    break;
  }
  return num1;
}
int main(void) {
  float num1;
  num1 = get_float_input_func();
  printf("%f\n", num1);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fseek(stdin, 0, SEEK_END);` is uncommon.  Who or what text suggested that?

Comment: this worked perfectly. Thank you for explaining this!

Comment: @chux the idea is that when scanf doesn't read correctly then the input remains in the input buffer and the file pointer is not moved. So in this case since we want a new input every time, we need to move the file pointer at the end of the stdin.

Comment: `fseek(stdin, 0, SEEK_END);` is not certainly a standard C compliant method to advance `stdin` as desired and so risks _undefined behavior_ (UB).  A simple alternative is to use `fgetc()` to read 1 character, throw it away and then try `scanf()` again.

Comment: I see what you are saying but fseek is a commonly used function when you do file handling in C. Using fgetc() won't be beneficial here since we want to get rid of the previous input(not just a single character). Hope you got my point. Also fgetc() is rarely used while reading a file since it is very slow because it doesn't read a block, but reads a single character, and hence we generally read a block of characters in a buffer while doing file I/O. Hope you got my point

Comment: That's interesting. But apparently not going to work with input redirected from file.

Comment: @shirish -- unlike streams associated with disk files, streams associated with terminals are not guaranteed to be seekable, meaning that `fseek(stdin, ...)` can fail. There are other better, portable, idiomatic solutions to this problem.

Comment: Yes that's true, I have modified the code to use a portable way. Check it out